# Problem with solc-x version

Tags: solidity, python

I am having trouble with installing solidity compiler on Python through Visual Studio Code on Windows. I went through solutions in other pages but none helped. Any idea?
I get the following error in a terminal:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip3.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Comment: what function did you run to get this?

Comment: pip install py-solc-x